# Gd Library Flip image and saving it

Tags: php, jquery, gd

I am using PHP GD library to flip an image and then save that flipped image. However I am able to flip image successfully but I don’t know how to save it with another name in a folder. My code is

```
$filename = '324234234234.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imageflip($im, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
imagejpeg($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a second parameter to imagejpeg($im) call with the path to the file you want to store.

```
imagejpeg($im, 'path/to/new/file.jpg');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: i used this but it show me error "image can't be displayed because it contains error "

Comment: also the raw image don't create need help please

Comment: It should work, the image won't be visible when loading the page because if you set a path it won't show the image but store it in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [`imagejpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) where it explains the second parameter relates to `$filename`:

> **bool** imagejpeg ( **resource** $image [, **string** $filename [, **int** $quality ]] )
>
> The path to save the file to. If not set or **NULL**, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.

So just add the new filename as a second parameter like this; assuming the name of the new name is `new_filename.jpg`. Also comment out or completely remove the `header` line so you are not outputting the image to the browser, but rather saving it to a file so the `header` isn’t needed:

```
$filename = '324234234234.jpg';
// header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imageflip($im, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
imagejpeg($im, 'new_filename.jpg');
```

Also note that while [`imageflip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageflip.php) is nice to use it is only available in PHP 5.5 & higher; it won’t be available in PHP 5.4 or lower:

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)
>
> image flip — Flips an image using a given mode

So if you want to use it in PHP 5.4 or lower, you need to create the logic to flip it on your own in the code or use [a function like this](http://maettig.com/?page=PHP/imageflip). It only flips horizontally so you would have to adjust it to flip vertically, but posting here so you have something to explore & work with if needed:

```
/**
 * Flip (mirror) an image left to right.
 *
 * @param image  resource
 * @param x      int
 * @param y      int
 * @param width  int
 * @param height int
 * @return bool
 * @require PHP 3.0.7 (function_exists), GD1
 */
function imageflip(&$image, $x = 0, $y = 0, $width = null, $height = null)
{
    if ($width  < 1) $width  = imagesx($image);
    if ($height < 1) $height = imagesy($image);
    // Truecolor provides better results, if possible.
    if (function_exists('imageistruecolor') && imageistruecolor($image))
    {
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(1, $height);
    }
    else
    {
        $tmp = imagecreate(1, $height);
    }
    $x2 = $x + $width - 1;
    for ($i = (int) floor(($width - 1) / 2); $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        // Backup right stripe.
        imagecopy($tmp,   $image, 0,        0,  $x2 - $i, $y, 1, $height);
        // Copy left stripe to the right.
        imagecopy($image, $image, $x2 - $i, $y, $x + $i,  $y, 1, $height);
        // Copy backuped right stripe to the left.
        imagecopy($image, $tmp,   $x + $i,  $y, 0,        0,  1, $height);
    }
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I try it But it dont work and also the raw image does not create need more help please

Comment: Yes i am completely Sure it nor create nor saved

Comment: after commenting the header Line it also don't work the flipping work as the link shows http://beta.technology-architects.com/javaid/ but i need to save this flipped image

Comment: Thank You Sir it's Done need to comment the header line and allow permits to copy the image to folder Thank you very Much appreciate on Your Help Once Again Thanks

Comment: Yes it is as and it completes my needs